# Yii with ob_gzhandler; Compression html

Tags: php, html, yii

I have add this code to configration file `main.php` on Yii to compress html markups

```
'preload'=>array('log'),
    'onBeginRequest' => create_function('$event', 'return ob_start("ob_gzhandler");'),  
    'onEndRequest' => create_function('$event', 'return ob_end_flush();'),
```

but I have conflict with zlib how can I fix that ?

```
ob_start(): output handler 'ob_gzhandler' conflicts with 'zlib output compression'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google pagespeed module for Apache is worked with me, and it's pre-installed on dreamhost and some web hosting:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module

Answer (score 3):

You had better **minify** html code at yii level

leaving gzip compressing to apache by using a segment like this in .htaccess

```
<IfModule deflate_module>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/json application/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Do NOT compress localhost
#SetEnvIf Remote_Host 127.0.0.1 no-gzip

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug with PHP 5.4: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62335

You may need to disable `zlib` maybe with something like:

```
<?php ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); ?>
```

Comment: I can disable form htaccess but still html not compressed

Comment: I'm using mod_pagespeed now it's great